# How do you define a macro that accepts struct pointer arguments in C?

Tags: c, macros, struct

I'm having trouble with the following task. In particular, I have a struct:

```
typedef struct {
  int x;
  int y;
} foo;
```

I am trying to define the following operation as a macro:

```
#define DO_SOMETHING(a,b) ((foo){a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y})
```

I try to run the code below, but I'm getting an error from the compiler stating that `left operand of "." must be pointer to struct/union`

```
int main()
{
  foo a = {1,2};
  foo b = {3,4};
  foo c = DO_SOMETHING(a,b);
  return 0;
}
```

I've looked around for a while to try to figure out what I'm doing wrong, but I haven't been able to find a good answer. I was wondering if I could get some help with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Apparently you are using a compiler for C89/C90. The language as defined by 1999 or later should accept your program as is. "Compound literals" were introduced in C99.

Comment: The code you show compiles cleanly for me using GCC 4.9.1 on Mac OS X 10.10.2 Yosemite — under stringent compilation options.  Please show the code that is actually causing your problem, not an approximation to it.  The only key trick is that I specify `-std=c11`; you need to specify C99 or C11 (so `-std=c99` or `-std=gnu99` or `-std=gnu11` would also work).

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you are using a compiler for C89/C90.

The language as defined by 1999 or later should accept your program as is.
"Compound literals" were introduced in C99.